# Laravel, how do I write this query to display records with fields from different tables and how would I update them?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I am thinking of implementing a schema design like this one http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/event_reservations/index.htm

I will need to display an *attendance sheet* that displays the customer names and seats for an event. How do I do I write the query/queries in a way that lets me easily display the data and update it if necessary?

Comment: Do you want to update the query? or update the data?

Comment: After I display the attendance sheet, I might need to update some fields and update the data in the database.

Comment: I think the sql would be this.
select customer.name, set_bookings.seatnumber
from customer_bookings
innerjoin customers 
on customer_bookings.customer_id=customers.customer_id
innerjoin seat_bookings 
on customer_bookings.booking_id=seat_bookings_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Eloquent and your models are set up correctly, an example of your query would be:

```
$reservations = CustomerBooking::where('event_id', $id)
    ->with('event', 'customer', 'seat')->get();
```

In the view:

```
Event Name: {{ $reservations->event->event_name->first() }} at {{ $reservations->event->venue->venue_name->first() }}
{{ $reservations->event->event_start_date->first() }} to {{ $reservations->event->event_end_date->first() }}
```

Customer stuff:

```
@foreach($reservations as $reservation)
Name: {{ $reservation->customer->customer_name }}
Seat: {{ $reservation->seat->seat_number }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I think I understand...could you add the model for CustomerBooking?